# Jelastic built-in file deployment manager did not delete old .htaccess files

Tags: jelastic

If you deploy projects via built-in deployment manager, it will delete all old files but not .htaccess file in the root folder.

You can run into problems with it - newly deployed project may not even start because of a wrong, old .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this behaviour - manually delete .htaccess file before deployment.